# How to address f# pipeline parameter by name?

Tags: f#, pipeline

I'm trying to do something like

```
seq { 1..100 }
|> Seq.sum
|> pown 2
```

It doesn't even compile cause pown expects 'T^' argument as first argument and i'm giving it as a second one, as this is default behavior of pipeline. By googling i didnt find the way to make "pown" use the param carried by pipeline as it's first arg. Maybe it has some default name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a lambda to give the incoming value a name:

```
seq { 1..100 } 
|> Seq.sum 
|> (fun x -> pown x 2)
```

Above, I named it `x`.

Comment: So i can't address that variable by some name like _$, _@, whatever? That's strange.

Comment: If by "strange" you mean "unlike insane perl", then yes, it is strange.  :)

Answer (score 5):

you can use auxiliary function:

```
let flip f x y = f y x

seq { 1L..100L }
    |> Seq.sum
    |> flip pown 2
```

It will be neat to have **flip** in standard library :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't usually use pipeline if the arguments do not match, because I feel that it can hurt the readability. The option by Brian is quite clear, but it is not much different from assigning the result to a value (using `let` instead of using pipeline and `fun`).

So, I would just write this (without any nice functional magic):

```
let x = seq { 1 .. 100 } |> Seq.sum
pown x 2
```

This is essentially the same as Brian's version - you're also assigning the result to a value - but it is more straightforward. I would probably use more descriptive name e.g. `sumResult` instead of `x`.

The version using `flip` is pretty standard thing to do in Haskell - though I also thing that it may become difficult to read (not in this simple case, but if you combine multiple functions, it can easily become horrible). That's I think also a reason why `flip` (and others) are missing in the F# libraries.